# Is `new` in JavaScript just syntactic sugar for `.call`?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I was wondering if there is anything special about `new` or if it is just syntactic sugar for `call()`. If I have a constructor like:

```
function Person ( name, age ){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}
```

is

```
var bob = new Person( "Bob", 55 );
```

any different than

```
var bob;
Person.call( bob = new Object(), "Bob", 55 );
```

?

Comment: They are not equivalent, the equivalent version would be `Person.call( bob = Object.create(Person.prototype), "Bob", 55 );`. Is it syntactic sugar? Might depend on how you define it. `Object.create` was not available in earlier JS versions.

Comment: @FelixKling probably should make that an answer instead of a comment, it's a good one. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not equivalent in your example, because `bob` does not inherit from `Person.prototype` (it directly inherits from `Object.prototype`).

The equivalent version would be

```
Person.call(bob = Object.create(Person.prototype), "Bob", 55 );
```

Is it syntactic sugar? Might depend on how you define it.

`Object.create` was not available in earlier JS versions, so it was not possible to set up object inheritance without `new` (you are able to overwrite the [internal `__proto__` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) of an object in some browsers, but that is really bad practice).

---

As a reference, how `new` works is defined in http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2 and http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2. `Object.create` is described in http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.3.5.

Answer (score 2):

No, `new` is not *just* syntactic sugar. On the contrary, `Person.call` works (and only works) to construct a new instance because [JavaScript allows constructors to be called without `new` in some cases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928342/javascript-using-constructor-without-operator-new)

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

`call()` merely invokes a function (see also `apply()`) whereas the `new` keyword initializes an object from a prototype.

While it's true that a prototype constructor is a function, it's a special case.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not.  If your first example, you are actually creating a Person.

```
bob instanceof Person == true
```

In the other example...

```
bob instanceof Person == false
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of creating an instance of a type is to share some behavior, usually through the prototype.

Let's say you add a function :

```
Person.prototype.doSomething = function(){
   ...
}
```

Then this function will be available for all objects created as instances of `Person` using `new`, but not to the object you create using `call`.

The MDN has a [good introductory document about the use of the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Answer (score 1):

When you call `new`, you are invoking the function as a constructor.  This tells JavaScript, to make a "new" `Person` object, and then call the function with that new object set as `this`.

In your 2nd example, you are calling the function normally, and manually setting `this` to a `new Object` (or just `{}`).  So, the function runs, and sets properties of the `this` object you sent it.  (Try just doing `Person( "Bob", 55 );`, then `console.log(window.name)`)

In the 1st example, `bob` is a `Person` object; but in the 2nd, it's an `Object`.

So, no, one is not short for the other.  They are different.