# Are there problems with calling JavaScript constructors as functions(without new?)

Tags: javascript

Recently, I have got into a habit of calling things like RegExp, String, Number, Object, TypeError, etc without "new".

e.g:

```
throw (TypeError("Error"));
var regex = RegExp('^word$');
```

I know that this is bad for cases when "this" context is needed, since without "new", "this" wreaks havoc on your global scope unless you wrap your code in 'use strict', in which case it raises an error that you are trying to mutate 'undefined'. (I am not sure that this works in very very old browsers).

e.g:

```
var constructor = function() {
    // 'use strict'; /* uncomment this line to avoid the behavior and be warned */
    this.state = 'working as intended';
};

var foo = constructor();
console.log(foo.state); // undefined
console.log(window.state); // we just polluted our global scope.
```

whereas

```
var constructor = function() {
    this.state = 'working as intended';
};

var foo = new constructor;
console.log(foo.state); // "working as intended"
console.log(window.state); // we are clean.
```

But in cases like the ones above, is it okay to do this, or are there problems I am setting myself up for if I get into a habit of doing this?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 8):

Be aware the result can be different.

For example, the `Number` constructor creates Number objects, but when called as a function it only does type coercion to primitive Number.

```
new Number(123); // Number { 123 }
Number(123); // 123
```

But yes, there are lots of the cases in which it doesn't matter whether you use `new` or not. They exist because of backwards compatibility, but with recently introduced constructors like `Set` or `Map` do require `new`.

In general, I would recommend using `new` when you want to create a new object. Then,

- If you only want to do type coercion, you must call `Boolean`, `Number` or `String` without `new`.
- For the same reason, if you want coerce to Object type, I wouldn't use `new`, but it doesn't matter.
- If you want to create a primitive which doesn't have literal syntax, you must call `Symbol` without `new`.
- If you want to create an object wrapper of a primitive value, you must call `Boolean`, `Number`, `String` or `Symbol` with `new`.
- If you want to instantiate an old constructor like `Array`, `Object`, `RegExp`, `Error`, etc., I would use `new`, but it doesn't matter.
- If you want to instantiate a recently introduced constructor like `Set`, `Map`, `WeakSet`, `WeakMap`, typed arrays, etc., you must call it with `new`.

For the old constructors that it doesn't matter, it's like they call themselves with `new` if you omit it. For example, for [`RegExp`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp-constructor),

> When `RegExp` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initializes a new RegExp object. Thus the function call
>   `RegExp(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression
>   `new RegExp(…)` with the same arguments.

Comment: So you are saying for things like RegExp and TypeError, and String(for concatenation context), it is perfectly fine?

Comment: @Dmitry It's fine for [The RegExp Constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp-constructor) and [The Error Constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-error-constructor). Not for String, Boolean, Number.

Comment: so doing things like `console.log(String(1392))` instead of `console.log(1392.toString())` or `console.log('' + 1392)` or just `console.log(1392)` is not okay?

Comment: @Dmitry Ah, no, I meant `new String(1392)` and `String(1392)` do different things. Usually you want `String(1392)`.

Comment: It's okay if it does what you want. If what you want is to create an object, you'll have to either use `new` or check the documentation to make sure the call without `new` creates an object.

Comment: I am now kinda curious how String, RegExp, TypeError create objects even though they are not called with new. Do they call new within themselves? Nevermind, `var a = RegExp(); console.log(a.prototype);` is undefined, so it wasn't created with new. Double nevermind, even with new it's undefined. O.o

Comment: @Dmitry Only constructors have a `prototype` property.

Answer (score 3):

As documented in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928342/javascript-using-constructor-without-operator-new), some built in constructors are written to be able to be called as functions. So as long as you aren't polluting your global namespace, I believe you should be fine with the example you listed.

That being said, in most cases, I wouldn't get used to this habit; the `new` operator adds to code clarity, which is more important than brevity. The ability to use native constructors without the `new` operator is also inconsistently applied across constructors.