# Do you need to use the word "new" when assigning a RegExp?

Tags: javascript

The right way to assign a RegExp to a variable is by using "new", since it's a constructor, but it also works without it, like in this example:

```
var a = RegExp('abc');
var b = new RegExp('abc');
console.log(a, b, "abcd".match(a), "abcd".match(b), a == b);
```

output: /abc/ /abc/ Array["abc"] Array["abc"] false

So my question is - do I need to use "new"?

On the other hand a == b fails, so are they different somehow, because their objects look the same?

Comment: You could also use a `/abc/` regex-literal.

Answer (score 4):

They are exactly equivalent. See [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp-constructor):

> The RegExp constructor:

> creates and initializes a new RegExp object when called as a function rather than as a constructor. Thus the function call RegExp(…) **is equivalent to the object creation expression new RegExp(…) with the same arguments.**

That said, using the constructor when not necessary is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55793086), because it can lead to bugs and hard-to-read code due to backslashes having to be double escaped. When you can, consider using regex literals instead, whose backslashes do *not* have to be double-escaped.

Comment: I do have a more complex regexp that is dynamic, so I can not use literals. On the other hand, examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp use "new" even for the simplest case, so that's quite misleading then.

Comment: On that link, I see how they're showing how using a regex literal and `new RegExp` can be equivalent, with different syntax, but after the syntax is defined, all of the examples below look to use regex literals (which is good). Are you seeing an unnecessary use of `new` somewhere?

Comment: You can equally show how using a regex literal and RegExp can be equivalent, without "new". Why did they provide an example with "new" if it's (1)not necessary, (2)bad idea?  Anyway, I'll accept you answer because my question is not about the quality of moz documentation.

Comment: It's not that `new` is a bad idea, it's that using the constructor *at all* is a bad idea when not necessary (but sometimes it's necessary, like in your case). I was going to edit the MDN page if I saw a place where it was using the constructor unnecessarily (when not simply describing the syntax), but I don't see any problems with it.

Comment: @alikim I saw the unaccept, was there an issue?

Comment: There is **no issue** about this special `RegExp`, even in the mentioned reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#syntax ... but about general use, this is a good explain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1928468/7514010

Answer (score 0):

The RegExp constructor also can be used to copy an existing regex,

```
var r1 = /abc/
var r2 = new RegExp(r1)
```